# ¿Cómo configuro la orientación en Android Studio correctamente?

Tags: android

Tengo un problema al configurar la orientación, la no debe rotar si se activa la rotación de la pantalla este es mi código:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
 }
```

No rota la Aplicación esté o no encendida la rotación de la tablet, pero invierte la aplicación es decir la parte superior la toma como la parte inferior
¿Cómo arreglo el problema?

Comment: Hola Julio, La primera linea al crear la Activity, me refiero dentro de onCreate() debe ser : setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

Comment: Que diferencia existe en cuanto la construcción del código?

Comment: Es que primero se define que siempre se tenga la orientación SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT y después se construye la UI de la Activity.

Comment: Bueno gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es casí correcto lo que realizas, pero para que funciona debes asegurar agregar `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` antes de  `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
    ...
}
```

obviamente debes tener agregada la propiedad `screenOrientation="portrait"` para tu `Activity` en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<activity android:name=".myActivity"
    ...
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Prueba de agregar la orientación en el manifest.xml donde declaras tu activity, algo así:

```
<activity android:name=".MiActividad"
          android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Suerte!